# Trouble Drawing Circles on an HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, html5-canvas

I've been drawing rectangles on an HTML canvas just fine, but my project requires the use of circles as well, which don't seem to work. The rectangles are drawn with this:

```
var myGameArea = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    start: function () {
        this.canvas.width = 300;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, ) {
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;

   ctx = myGameArea.context;
   ctx.fillStyle = color;
   ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

How can I draw circles using a similar method?

Comment: https://lmgtfy.app/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=js%20canvas%20draw%20circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point for this is the HTML Canvas Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp
It provides hints to this particular question and even for further requirements of your project.

According to this refernce your particular problem can be solved using the arc() method. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp

If you would want to fill it, the mentioned fill() method helps: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fill.asp

Hope that solved this and further challenges.